# I am getting reference error while adding the OrchardCMS in .NET Core application

Tags: c#, .net

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKqSC.png)

[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzEoa.png)

I am trying to add `IServiceCollection.AddOrchardCms();` and I am getting the following error:

```
Error   CS1061  'IServiceCollection' does not contain a definition for 'AddOrchardCms' and no accessible extension method 'AddOrchardCms' accepting a first argument of type 'IServiceCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  WebApplication1 D:\vibhan_pro\CMS\WebApplication1\WebApplication1\Startup.cs    15  Active
```

Comment: I assume you added OrchardCMS as "Add Existing object" and then browsed to folder where it was located.  Did you add a using statement at top of module?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please copy/paste your actual source code into the question post, and please do not use **images** of your code.